# How can i log to console meteor network requests

Tags: node.js, meteor

I found a command to run meteor with a verbose debug settings that logs network requests to the console, and i can't find it anywhere again.
What is the command?

Comment: If it is part of Meteor it should be found in the [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) and / or the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/). Search is on your own.

Comment: Yeah i searched for over an hour for it

Comment: Have you tried Meteor DevTools chrome extension for client side network requests?

Answer (score 1):

Found it if anyone gets stuck:

```
NODE_DEBUG=request meteor
```

Comment: Can you link the resource where you found the info? Maybe relevant for others as well.